# Decimal values stopping at first decimal in c#

Tags: c#, math, double, decimal

I am trying to figure out why my decimal values are not being stored correctly.  This is an example equation:

```
//Comes up as 0.0
double foo = 120 / 175;
// Want to convert to look like a percent but comes up as 0.0 also
double bar = foo * 100;
```

I know 120/175 is 0.6857.... any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're performing arithmetic on two integers, so the result is an integer. You lose the fractional part of the result before it's stored in `foo`.

You should convert one of the values to a `double` first:

```
double foo = 120d / 175;
```

You can do this with `decimal`s too, if that's what you're actually trying to use:

```
decimal foo = 120m / 175;
```

Once you've properly captured the decimal value from the first equation, this part should work fine:

```
decimal bar = foo * 100;
```